# Reference for problems on explicit compuation of Radon Nikodym derivative

Tags: measure-theory

I have been looking for books/references that have good number of exercise on computation of Radon Nikodym deriative for explicit examples...most of the books/references that I have come across contains exercise that more of a proof-based nature...I would like to have reference where one can find exercises such as

[Calculation of Radon–Nikodym derivative](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1118755/calculation-of-radon-nikodym-derivative)

[Calculating Explicit Radon-Nikodym Derivatives](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2835283/calculating-explicit-radon-nikodym-derivatives)

[Computing an explicit Radon-Nikodym derivative](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1046679/computing-an-explicit-radon-nikodym-derivative)

[Explicit Radon-Nikodym decomposition](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2122664/explicit-radon-nikodym-decomposition)

I do hope that any such reference would consist many such problems on signed/complex measures, differentiation, functions of bounded variations, fundmanetal theorem of calculus etc.